# Obtener un dato especifico de una coleccion en Laravel

Tags: laravel

en esta parte de código quiero extraer un numero que represente el stock de un producto en una tabla de mysql

```
$actualStock = DB::table('products')->select(DB::raw('actual_stock'))->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
```

Al hacer un dd de lo siguente

```
$stock = $actualStock->all();
dd($stock);
```

me da la siguiente respuesta
[image]
quiero extraer ese 12 como un int

Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: no tienes el Modelo para `products`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solo va a retornar un registro tu consulta, entonces puedes hacer los siguientes cambios:

- Quita el método `select()`
- Usemos el método `first()` para solo obtener un objeto en lugar de una colección
- Al final de la consulta accedemos a la propiedad deseada que en este caso es el *stock_actual* encadenándola a la misma
- Podemos simplificar un poco la sintaxis del método `where`

La consulta se vería así:

```
$actualStock = DB::table('products')->whereId($id)->first()->actual_stock;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias <3